# upload file to build artifacts for specific build in azure devops - REST API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to upload a a file as artifact to specific build using REST API.
I found this link to create a artifacts for a build
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#referencelinks

Can someone help me to prepare the json request body with the local file path to upload?

If it is not possible to upload a file as artifact from my local machine, please let me know.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Would also like to know how/if this works